# Restrict Keyword to be published in Taxonomy for local sites

Tags: keyword, taxonomy, localization

We have a requirement where we need to restrict publishing of certain Keywords of a Cateogry, for only 1 local site.

All Category/Keywords are created in 100 Schemas level, (so they are inherited for all brand sites as well as all local sites).

1 solution is to put a metadata Schema on the Keyword - and read the metadata field value when retrieving the taxonomy list.

Do we have any other way to restrict publishing of some Keywords for local sites?

Note: Our solution makes use of Taxonomy for providing dropdown options on the website.

Earlier, we were fetching Category/Keywords from Content store using `TaxonomyFactory`, but now publishing Category/Keyword tree as JSON (reading them in C# TBB and composing the JSON). So adding Keyword metadata, would be a good solution for this requirement.

Kindly suggest if there is any other better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that using metadata on each (presumably, localised) keyword and then filtering these out with your C# TBB would be a reasonably elegant and maintainable solution.

Alternatively (and depending on your requirements!), you could also use a naming convention on the keyword value (e.g. Prefix the keyword's `Value` field with something like "HIDE - "), but keep the `Key` the same, for the ones you want to omit and filter these out in the TBB. This would have the advantage of being immediately visible in the CME GUI.

[image: Image of keyword value change]